# How to make a full-width UITextField in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm very new to Swift, like one week new and I'd like to come up with a 100% width UITextField. The expected result is that the text field should be 100% of the screen's width.

This is what I've done for iPhone 5 displays having a 320px vertically centered TextField.

[image]

That looks as expected, but when I'm going on iPhone 6, this happens:
[image]

How is it possible to make this 100% of the screen's width? As I can only see fixed width inputs in size inspector.

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: I'm using autolayout ( constraints ) to center those horrizontally and keep the heights. If you could explain how to use autolayout to set full width, that'd be great as I couldn't find out the right tutorial on the internet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not specify the width but the leading and trailing space of the textfield to its superview:

- select the `UITextField` you want to align
- click on the `Pin` icon
- uncheck the "Constrain to margins"
- set the leading to 0
- set the trailing to 0

[image]

which will result in the TextField to span the entire width on every screen:

[image]

Note that you sometimes have to specify the view you want to set the space relative to:

[image]

Comment: You shitting me... I've tried that so many times.. but I was using that Constrain to margins... I feel weird. Thanks, I can accept in 3 minutes at least.

Comment: @edduvs Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use auto layout and constraints,

if you wish, you can do it manually using code:

```
//full screen size
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
textInput.frame.size.width = screenWidth
```

Comment: are you using interface builder?

Comment: Daniel Krom, yes I am